# adding filename to an empty file in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am already adding the name of the file as an identifier *for downstream steps.

by using the following command

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"};
{print FILENAME, $0}' $i > appended.$i
```

say I have the file contents of CELLLINE1.txt as

```
chr2 1020120 1202420 5
```

by following the aforesaid command I am adding a column with the filename in it

```
CELLLINE1.txt chr2 1020120 1202420 5
```

Is it possible to do the same in an empty file (0 bytes) with no contents.

any suggestions please

Comment: Where would you add the identifier? The problem is *underspecified* I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an `if` outside of the `awk` statement:

```
test 0 -eq $(wc -l test | cut -d" " -f 1)&& echo $i > appended.$i || awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"};{print FILENAME, $0}' $i > appended.$i
```

You could also do this inside awk with some variables:

```
awk 'BEGIN{{FS=OFS="\t"}{linecount==0}}{linecount+=1}{print FILENAME, $0} END{if (linecount==0) print FILENAME}' $i > appended.$i
```

The new variable `linecount` is set to `0` at `BEGIN` and then tested in the `END` to see if it's still `0`. If so, it prints the `FILENAME`